# How to activate SOAP on php5.6

Tags: php, ubuntu, soap, wsdl

When I check `service soap status` in Ubuntu, it says:

```
root@ip-172-30-0-181:/var/www# service soap status
soap.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: SOAP is not a linux "service" like the apache2 service (webserver). Do you mean a SOAP webservice?

Answer (score 3):

run thecommands :

Install soap php module :

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-soap
```

info de soap :

```
php -i | grep -i soap

apt-cache search php | grep -i soap
```

enbale soap in php.ini :

```
cd /etc/php/5.6/apache2

sudo nano php.ini
```

you see this :

```
;extension=php_soap.dll
```

change for this :

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

and save an restar apache service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and see your info.php and you can see soap enable

and see this in your browser

Comment: php_soap.dll for a Linux OS? This is a library for Windos only.

Answer (score -1):

You mean SOAP module,

1. Go to your server php folder installation
2. Look extension=php_soap.dll in php.ini and remove the semicolon(;)
3. Restart your Server

Comment: The author asked about Ubuntu. DLL are extension for Windows library only.